# REGEX how to split on: * , and the phrase "D/ST"?

Tags: regex, string, split

I've used regex before and am familiar with string.split but I can't figure out how to split on the delimiters: * and , and the phrase, "D/ST".

when i do string.split("[,*|D/ST]+" with a pipe it just splits on the letter D.

Anyone do something like this before?

Comment: you need to escape the `*`. Use `\*`

Comment: will a single string contain both delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your previous regex didn't work is because you're using a *character class*, which will match a single character of those. Instead, [you should probably use grouping](http://regexr.com?36up1), which is separated by vertical bars:

```
(\*|\,|D\/ST)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I'm going to bookmark that site. I'll give this a check mark in 7 minutes.

Comment: You're faster than me :)
Just, I would add a + in your regex to better manage the case of successive delimiters

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Ordinarily, I'd agree, though in this case, it may be important to know how many times a string was split, so having successive splits could be (though isn't necessarily) important.

Answer (score 0):

Have you an example of the input string?

Try something like :

```
"(\,|\*|D\/ST)+"
```

No "OR" in an interval...